# Compare date with previous date in loop

Tags: php

I'm looping through a query which contain a value which is an integer and a datetime. I want to compare the every row in the loop and if a record with the same date(NOT TIME) already exists it should delete the previous record/object in the array. How can i achieve this?

```
foreach ($balanceQuery as $row) 
{ 

    $value = $row->balance;


    $datetime = strtotime($row->post_date) * 1000;
    $data[] = "[$datetime, $value]";
}
```

Comment: to achieve this your need to compare each row with previous ones and delete it if found

Comment: You should be doing that in an SQL query statement.

Comment: I've been advised to do it in this statement due to the complexity of my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please let me try.

```
$tempDates = array();
$tempDelete = array(); 
foreach ($balanceQuery as $key=>$row){ 
    $value = $row->balance;
    $datetime = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row->post_date)); // make format just date
    if(in_array($datetime, $tempDates)){ // if date is exist in $tempDates
        $keys = array_keys($tempDates, $datetime); // get the keys
        if(!empty($keys)){
             $tempDelete[] = $keys[count($keys)-1]; // put the last exist date
        }
    }
    $tempDates[$key] = $datetime; // store to array with $key array
}

// now looping for delete

foreach($tempDelete as $del){
    unset($balanceQuery[$del]);
}
```